# Locale p-calendar primeng Angular

Tags: angular

Olá!

Estou utilizando o componete p-calendar do primeng e setando o locale dele para pt conforme abaixo:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="filtro.dataEmissaoIni" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" name="datai" [locale]="pt" [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar>
```

E no typescript deste componente está configurados os valores para pt :

```
this.pt = {
  firstDayOfWeek: 0,
  dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado'],
  dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],
  dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Se', 'Te', 'Qu', 'Qu', 'Se', 'Sa'],
  monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho',
    'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
  monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
  today: 'Hoje',
  clear: 'Limpar'
};
```

Está funcionando corretamente, só que em todos componentes que vou usar preciso por esta configuração.

Gostaria de saber como usar colocando está configuração em um só local e usar no programa todo.

Aqui meu package.json

```html
{
  "name": "suporteti",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "ng2-cpf-cnpj": "^0.1.1",
    "primeng": "^5.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Se alguém poder me dar uma ideia.
Agradeço.

Comment: por gentileza poderia colocar o código do arquivo package.json? Pois a configuração do Angular 5 é feita de forma diferente e para isso preciso saber as configurações do seu arquivo package.json

Comment: Coloquei acima conforme solicitou...@wladyband

Answer (score 0):

Você pode retirar essas linhas de código do seu componente:

```
this.pt = {
  firstDayOfWeek: 0,
  dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado'],
  dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],
  dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Se', 'Te', 'Qu', 'Qu', 'Se', 'Sa'],
  monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho',
    'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
  monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
  today: 'Hoje',
  clear: 'Limpar'
};
```

Adicionar essa biblioteca no seu module.service.ts

```
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';

imports: [

   { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'pt-BR' }

  ],
```

Seu HTML ficará assim:

```
     <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="filtro.dataEmissaoIni" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" name="datai"  [showIcon]="true"></p-calendar>
```

Seu arquivo package.json em vez de ficar asssim :

```
{
  "name": "suporteti",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "ng2-cpf-cnpj": "^0.1.1",
    "primeng": "^5.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Tem que fica mais ou menos assim, você vai ter que adaptar:

```
{
  "name": "suporteti",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ng2-currency-mask": "^4.1.0",
    "ng2-toasty": "^4.0.3",
    "primeng": "^4.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Se tiver problemas me avise.

Comment: Mas ai estarei mudando a versão do angular para a anterior estou usando a versão 5. A questão ali do { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'pt-BR' } não funciona mais no 5 tem que usar só pt e dar um Import no app module assim: import localePt from '@angular/common/locales/pt';

Comment: Eu entendo que queria implementar o seu projeto de acordo com a nova versão, eu também estou aprendendo Angular, talvez você saiba mexer com o Angular melhor do que eu, mas o que costumo fazer é pegar códigos na internet que as pessoas usam e está funcionando enquanto não sei fazer da nova versão. A sugestão que fiz foi você mudar a sua versão do Angular 5 para o 4 e que a implementação do Locate provavelmente funcionária, enquanto você não tem algo melhor trabalha com que tem ou esperar alguém posta a sugestão que precisa.

Comment: Não existem muitas mudanças da versão do Angular do 4 para o 5, eu acredito que só tenha isso mesmo do Locate.

Comment: Mudei para a 5 por um outro problema que estava tendo e foi corrigido, o qual não estou lembrando agora. Ainda não achei nada na internet com essa resolução.

Answer (score 0):

Para não ficar sem uma resposta...

Pode colocar essas traduções nas configurações no PrimeNgConfig no seu app.components

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PrimeNGConfig } from 'primeng/api';
import { MenuProfile } from 'codevasf-menu-lateral';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private config: PrimeNGConfig) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.config.setTranslation({
        apply: 'Aplicar',
        clear: 'Limpar',
        accept: 'Sim',
        reject: 'Não',
        firstDayOfWeek: 0,
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sab'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Se', 'Te', 'Qu', 'Qu', 'Se', 'Sa'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho',
          'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
        today: 'Hoje'
    });
  }
}
```

E usar só o componente mesmo

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="filtro.dataEmissaoIni" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" name="datai" [showIcon]="true" ></p-calendar>
```